# kendo datetimepicker not setting the value to the viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datetimepicker

I am implementing the kendo datepicker in my MVC 5 application. I am not sure for what reason the viewmodel property is not being set with what is selected in the datetimepicker

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractStartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContractStartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@

                        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ContractStartDate)
                          .Name("contractdatepicker")
                          .Value("10/10/2011")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                        )

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractStartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `.Name("contractdatepicker")`. When this is rendered it will become the name and id tag on the `<input>` and therefore won't bind to your viewmodel. If you omit that attribute it will automatically add the name and id `ContractStartDate`. So, just remove that tag and if you refer to it in javascript change the reference to `#ContractStartDate`.